# glm overload operator for use in map dont work

Tags: c++, std, glm-math

I try use **glm::vec2** for key in **std::map** , but i have this error :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const glm::vec2' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  VoxelEngine C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xstddef  239

After search on google i found i need overload operator , I have try use that :

```
bool operator<(const glm::vec2& lhs, const glm::vec2& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x + lhs.y < rhs.x + rhs.y;
}
```

That is my tools.h

```
#pragma once
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


#include <..\glm/glm.hpp>
#include <..\glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <..\glm/mat4x4.hpp>
#include <..\glm/trigonometric.hpp>
// Include GLM extensions
#include <..\glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <..\glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <..\glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;
using namespace std;
bool operator<(const glm::vec2& lhs, const glm::vec2& rhs);
#include <map>
```

But it dont fix my error , how i can overload the operator ?

Comment: Huh? What's a "surcharge operator"?

Comment: i want say overload

Comment: Did you declare your `operator<()` in a header file that is included before declaring the `std::map`? Also, you probably want to remove the `|| lhs.y == rhs.y` part from your function.

Comment: I have edit my question for show you my header

Comment: `v < v` should always be false. Your function will make it true.

Comment: I have change that but is not the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the probleme i just need use overload in the good namespace, in my header i need use :

```
namespace glm {
    bool operator <(const glm::vec2& l, const glm::vec2& r);
    bool operator ==(const glm::vec2& l, const glm::vec2& r);
}
```

Thx all for your answer